# How to impute values derived from a grouped dataframe into another grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given two grouped dataframes (df_train & df_test), how do I fill the missing values of df_test using values derived from df_train? For this example, I used median.

```
df_train=pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','B','A','A','C','B','B','A','A','B','C'], 'col_2':[float('NaN'),2,1,3,1,float('NaN'),2,3,2,float('NaN'),1]})
df_test=pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','A','A','A','B','C','C','B','B','B','C'], 'col_2':[3,float('NaN'),1,2,2,float('NaN'),float('NaN'),3,2,float('NaN'),float('NaN')]})

# These are the median values derived from df_train which I would like to impute into df_test based on the column col_1.
values_used_in_df_train = df_train.groupby(by='col_1')['col_2'].median()
values_used_in_df_train
col_1
A    2.5
B    2.0
C    1.0
Name: col_2, dtype: float64


# For df_train, I can simply do the following:
df_train.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].transform(lambda x : x.fillna(x.median()))
```

I tried `df_test.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].transform(lambda x : x.fillna(values_used_in_df_train))` which does not work.

So I want:

```
df_test
col_1   col_2
0   A   3.0
1   A   NaN
2   A   1.0
3   A   2.0
4   B   2.0
5   C   NaN
6   C   NaN
7   B   3.0
8   B   2.0
9   B   NaN
10  C   NaN
```

to become

```
df_test
col_1   col_2
0   A   3.0
1   A   2.5
2   A   1.0
3   A   2.0
4   B   2.0
5   C   1.0
6   C   1.0
7   B   3.0
8   B   2.0
9   B   2.0
10  C   1.0
```

---

Below here are just my thoughts, you do not have to consider them since it might be irrelevant/confusing.

I guess I could use an if-else method to match row-by-row to the index of `values_used_in_df_train` but I am trying to achieve this within groupby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try merging df_test and values_used_in_df_train:

```
df_test=df_test.merge(values_used_in_df_train.reset_index(),on='col_1',how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))
```

Finally fill missing values by using `fillna()`:

```
df_test['col_2']=df_test['col_2'].fillna(df_test.pop('col_2_y'))
```

**OR**

Another way(If order is not important):

append df_test and values_used_in_df_train and then drop NaN's:

```
df_test=(df_test.append(values_used_in_df_train.reset_index())
            .dropna(subset=['col_2'])
            .reset_index(drop=True))
```